# Vue/Nuxt - Watch / computed length of array from a vue plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, nuxt.js

I want to display the length of an array in my vue component. The array is nested in a vue plugin.
Everytime I start an `API Call` I 'push' a new element in this array found here: `this.$apiCall.apiCallCache`

Is this possible to watch for changes on this array? Am I doing something wrong in the example below?

I only get `0` the hole time. But if I click on the button and trigger `logApiCache()` it will console.log the right length of the array while the computed function still shows 0 in the span element / tooltip.

```
<template>
    <v-footer
        app
        tile
    >
        <span>Queue: {{ footerClockTooltip() }}</span>
        <app-footer-button
            :name="'Clock'"
            :tooltip="footerClockTooltip()"
            :icon="$icons.mdiClockOutline"
            @click="logApiCache"
        />
    </v-footer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Footer',
    computed: {
        /*
        footerClockTooltip() {
            return this.$apiCall.apiCallCache.length
        }
        */
    },
    methods: {
        logApiCache() {
            this.$forceUpdate()
            console.error(`logApiCache: ${this.$apiCall.apiCallCache.length}`, this.$apiCall.apiCallCache)
        },
        footerClockTooltip() {
            console.error('New Queue:', this.$apiCall.apiCallCache.length)
            return this.$apiCall.apiCallCache.length
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Edit:

Here is my Vue plugin:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
const ApiClass = require('../classes/ApiClass')
const api = new ApiClass()

// Export Vue Plugin
const ApiCalls = {
    install(Vue) {
        Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
            $apiCall: {
                get() {
                    return api
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

Vue.use(ApiCalls)
```

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Could you share the code in your plugin? I think it could be useful. Also which version of Nuxt are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your help. :) I added the files above, Here my version: `"nuxt": "2.12.2"`. The importan part for my array I want to watch is in `addCall` > `this.apiCallCache.push({ ... })`

Comment: Vue doesn’t keep a copy of the pre-mutate value so the issue might be that you are pushing data into an existing array instead of creating a new one and updating it with exisiting and new data.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? I'm a little lost. In my Vue plugin I create an instance from my `ApiClass`. Then I bind this instance to my Vue object, so I can access it with `this.$apiCall`. Now, if I start a request/api call in an seperate component, I just call `this.$smcApiCall.addCall(request, callback)`. The `addCall` function then pushs a new object into an array of the class property.

Comment: Even if I manually "push" data to this array, my computed function will not update my span element. But again, in the console.log is the right length as you see in this picture: [link](https://imgur.com/mA7qior)

Comment: Coul it be, that vue isn't detecting a change in the plugin? I added `this.$forceUpdate()` to my `@click="logApiCache"` function (edited in the first post) and it worked. So everytime I manually press the button above, the span element is updating correctly. Why doesn't it just happen on its own?

Comment: This works only if I use a method instead of a computed function?! Now I'm totally confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright... after a long search session I found a solution.
First step was adding a new property in my footer component mentioned above with a default value, `apicalls: null` for example. After that, I made a `created()` part in my component and linked the local property `apicalls` to `this.$apiCall.apiCallCache` and it was reactive. My computed function worked now.

After that I found an even simpler solution. I just need to assign my vue plugin in a different way `Vue.observable(api)`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
const ApiClass = require('../classes/ApiClass')
const api = new ApiClass()

// Export Vue Plugin
const ApiCalls = {
    install(Vue) {
        Vue.prototype.$apiCall = Vue.observable(api)
    }
}

Vue.use(ApiCalls)
```

Can someone please explain me, why this new way makes my array reactive, but not my first way?